# Get the changed value from OnValidate

Tags: c#, validation, unity-game-engine

Say I have a class with multiple variables that I want to check via OnValidate, it doesn't seem to make much sense to check every variable in said class every time I change one variable through the Unity Inspector. So is there a way to just check the variable that was changed?

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Stat
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float _value;

    Value { get; set; } 
}

public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Stat stat1;
    public Stat stat2;
    public Stat stat3;

    void Start(){}

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (stat1.Value < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error with stat1");
        }
        else if (stat2.Value < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error with stat2");
        }
        else if (stat3.Value < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error with stat3");
        }
    }
}
```

So in this case, everytime I change either stat1, stat2, or stat3 in Unity Inspector. OnValidate will go through and check every variable which doesn't seem very efficient. I'm wondering if there is a way to only get the value that was changed so my code can look something like this:

```
public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Stat stat1;
    public Stat stat2;
    public Stat stat3;

    void Start(){}

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (value < 0) // value being the value that was changed
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Error with {value}");
        }
    }
}
```

This shouldn't be too relevant but in case anyone is wondering why I have a Stat class, I am following a tutorial on creating character stats that have a SerializeField.

Edit: Added code examples for clarification

Comment: Can you please share an example class you're trying to add validations to so that answers can relate directly to your use case.

Comment: Added examples, hopefully this clarifies things

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a quick way to achieve this. You need to cache the values of fields in OnValidate and compare these cached values with the new values in following OnValidate calls to figure out the changed variable(s).